# Self-Documenting ActiveRecord Class Files in Rails 4 without attr_accessible

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

**Question:**
In a post-attr_accessible Rails 4 world, in what way do you recommend, if at all, annotating your ActiveRecord model class files to communicate its (database) attributes?

**Further Thoughts**

As part of a Rails 3 -> 4 upgrade, we are making a switch, and happily so, away from attr_accessible and to strong parameters in the controller. I understand and agree with the improvement in security via this switch. If you want to know more about this, the information is out there, and it's not hard to find.

But, I enjoyed, in my Rails 3 world, having those reminders of what attributes made up a class up there at the top of the model file. Especially since we're moving toward a world in which ActiveRecord classes are just DAOs, what else is the class but a collection of database attributes? I don't want to go to the schema.rb file just to remember them.

Am I thinking about this incorrectly? In a DAO world, should I be creating my ActiveRecord model class file and then never opening it again?

I know about the [annotate_models gem](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models) and used it way back in the day. I was not a fan of having the attributes described in commented-out lines. (unreadable, hackish, fragile)

Thoughts? Opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Person.column_names
```

If you are using an IDE or and editor that has a console feature this becomes an easy way to be reminded what attributes there are. I am no Ruby or Rails expert, still pretty new here, but I've been using Rails 4 almost exclusively and it just seems like you wouldn't need to see the attributes that often in the model. The params get whitelisted in the controller because that is where they will usually be used, no? If you don't want to use comments you could store an array of the attributes in the model:

```
my_attr = [:fname, :lname, :age, :height, :weight]
```

But is that really any more useful than a comment? Would there be a case of attributes that would have been in attr_accessible that wouldn't be in your whitelist in your controller? It would be trick if you put some code in a rake task that would run every time you ran

```
rake db:...
```

that would update the my_attr array in your model so you wouldn't have to remember to do it when you modified the model. I go into my models to add class methods and scopes, so I do see a value in it. But I work in RubyMine so I just click on the DB tab on the left side if I need to be reminded of columns that aren't in my whitelist.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer mostly on the basis of "you wouldn't need to see the attributes that often in the model." I think you're right.